# unable to alter routine in mysql

Tags: mysql

problem: unable to alter routines.

I'm using mysql 5.1.47. I created a user called 'testuser' and db's called "abc1,abc2,abc3".

At first I tried

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'testuser'@'%';(also::> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'testuser'@'%';)
```

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

tried this also

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'testuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'passwd';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

This works fine and user testuser was able to create,alter routines.

Then I revoked all the privileges and even deleted the user testuser and again created testuser. Then I tried:

```
GRANT ALL ON abc1.* TO 'testuser'@'%';
```

tried this also

```
GRANT ALL ON abc1.* TO 'testuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'passwd';
GRANT ALTER ROUTINE ON abc1.* TO 'testuser'@'%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

By using above methods (particular Db) I'm unable to alter routine.I tried all the hosts like localhost,%,127.0.0.1,local ip. I tried to alter routine using workbench, and it is blank without any error.

But testuser is able to create routine and able to edit routine created by testuser. But other routines which are created by some other users are not able to edit by testuser (both routines are in same db).

But when i give access to all db like:

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'testuser'@'%'; 
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

then testuser is able to edit all the routines. Please help me to fix this issue.

Thanks.
vijai

Answer (score 3):

I ran into a similar problem, where I created a new account for a junior developer via SQL Workbench with the following privileges on a specific schema:  *Alter, Alter Routine, Create, Create Routine, Delete, Execute, Insert, Select, Show View, Update*.

I also executed flush privileges from the work bench to ensure that the latest privileges were applied, but everytime he would right click on a stored procedure and choose **"Send to Sql Editor" -> Procedure Call** nothing would show up.  We tried changing all sorts of options and still couldn't get it to show up.

He was able to create new procedures and then edit these procedures, but could not edit or do anything except call existing procedures written by other users.  FYI, I'll add that he didn't have any DB Administrative Roles assigned.

After fiddling around and researching, I got the notion to try providing privileges on the mysql schema, since that schema has the definitions of the stored procedures in the proc table.  I started out by giving all privileges and whittled it down to just the "select" privilege on this schema, and after that, the developer was able to right click on the procedures and **"Send to Sql Editor" -> Procedure Call** as well as alter procedures.

I'm not 100% sure if this exactly solves your problem, but it does address a couple of items.

I'll also add that it is our security policy to provide the least amount of privileges possible for a user to do their work effectively, so reducing the number of privileges supplied is something to carefully consider.

Comment: Thank you a million times kind stranger from 8 years ago. This is exactly what I needed!
I had also granted all privileges to two named databases and could not alter stored procedures in them from the new user. 
I just added `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mysql.* TO 'myuser'@'%'` to my user and everything worked. 
I just added this in case someone else is wandering the web and has the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

You may need to flush priviliges:

```
flush privileges;
```

Or you may need something other than '%' (which I think might mean 'anything other than localhost')

I don't create any complicated grants in my work... but in testing systems, I always add 3 grants (3rd is for misconfigured /etc/hosts files which on some incorrectly configured systems map "localhost" to the first NIC IP):

```
grant all privileges on dbnamehere.* to username@'%' identified by 'passwordhere';
grant all privileges on dbnamehere.* to username@'localhost' identified by 'passwordhere';
grant all privileges on dbnamehere.* to username@'127.0.0.1' identified by 'passwordhere';
update mysql.user set password=OLD_PASSWORD('passwordhere') where user='username';
flush privileges;
```

Comment: % doesn't exclude localhost - the only reason you normal see the localhost and % as different users, is the localhost more often is granted higher permissions

Comment: Thanks for your replies,I tried %,localhost,127.0.0.1.with flush privileges option also.i can delete,create routines.But alter routine is not working :(

Comment: The latest community mysql is 5.5.23, so you should probably try that.

Comment: Grant all does not grant the ability to alter for me either.